# Understanding a datum declaration in typescript

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, typescript

At the bottom of this post are lines 52-68 of file `lucid-vesting` of week 4 (PPP fourth iteration).  I am having a hard time understanding line 60:

```typescript
const dtm: Datum = Data.to<VestingDatum>(datum,VestingDatum);
```

Why are there two instances of `VestingDatum`?  It seems that the command `to` is converting `datum` to `VestingDatum`, but `datum` had already been declared to be of type `VestingDatum`.

```typescript
// Creating a datum with a beneficiary and deadline
const datum: VestingDatum = {
    beneficiary: beneficiaryPKH,
    deadline: deadlinePosIx,
};

// An asynchronous function that sends an amount of Lovelace to the script with the above datum.
async function vestFunds(amount: bigint): Promise<TxHash> {
    const dtm: Datum = Data.to<VestingDatum>(datum,VestingDatum);
    const tx = await lucid
      .newTx()
      .payToContract(vestingAddress, { inline: dtm }, { lovelace: amount })
      .complete();
    const signedTx = await tx.sign().complete();
    const txHash = await signedTx.submit();
    return txHash
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucid also has a minimal example for typed data [here](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid/blob/main/src/examples/typed_data.ts).

The function `Data.to` has the following signature (as seen from [here](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid/blob/main/src/plutus/data.ts#L264)):

```typescript
/**
 * Convert PlutusData to Cbor encoded data.\
 * Or apply a shape and convert the provided data struct to Cbor encoded data.
 */
function to<T = Data>(data: T, shape?: Json): Datum | Redeemer {
```

Where the type `Data` which is a wrapper around your usual Plutus primitives (see [this](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid/blob/main/src/plutus/data.ts#L31)).

Lucid defines higher types [here](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid/blob/main/src/plutus/data.ts#L39) which correspond to their serialized version as one would expect.

Now seeing the definition of function `to` from Lucid's source code, you'll realize that it first wants to obtain this `Data` ([this](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid/blob/main/src/plutus/data.ts#L305) line) and then convert it for corresponding plutus types (the `serialize` function) in [Cardano Multiplatform Library](https://github.com/dcSpark/cardano-multiplatform-lib).
Now either you can play with so called raw/untyped datum (like in [this](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid/blob/main/src/examples/matching_keyhash.ts#L59) example) in which case your `T` above will simply be that `Data` or you can play at a bit higher type level (like you would do when writing Plutus contracts) where lucid helps you get this `T` using `Data.Static` as seen [here](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid/blob/main/src/examples/typed_data.ts#L19). The second parameter as you would understand by now, is not at type level and is for [this](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid/blob/main/src/examples/typed_data.ts#L13) - the shape of your structure. Also `Json` is essentially `any` type.